# How to correctly execute requests to the server in Polyglot Notebook js cells?

Tags: .net

How to correctly execute requests to the server in Polyglot Notebook js cells?

I use a Polyglot Notebook .NET, .ipynb file, and in the javascript code cell I want to make a request to the server using the built-in fetch method/axios, but for some reason I don’t get anything in the console, there are also no errors. What could be the problem?

```
require(['axios'], function (axios) {
  const url = 'http://myurl.com';
  const token = 'token';
  

  const body = {
    listFields: [],
    searchData: '',
    skip: 0,
    take: 50,
  };

  axios.post(url, body, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data.dataList);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

B"H

`console.log()` can not be called after the function has returned.
Your `.then()` function runs when the network results return. Which is after the cell has completed running. So the results can't be printed.

However Polyglot Notebook js cells are actually `async` functions. So you can use `await` right in the cell without wrapping it in a function.

```
So you can write
response = await fetch('http://myurl.com')
  .then(response => response.json())

console.log(response )
```

Which returns a Promise which is then awaited. The output is then written only when the Promise resolves.